# In SAS is there a way to compute the "canonical correlation" between two categorical variables using just a proc?

Tags: statistics, sas

I have two char variables in a dataset. I want to compute the canonical correlation between the two. By that I mean I want to create some dummy variables from the two categorical variables and compute the canonical correlation that way. After looking through proc cancorr I can not find a way to do this without first manually converting the categorical variables to dummy variables first. Is there a way to do that without manually converting the categorical variables to dummy variables first?

Answer (score 3):

[PROC GLMMOD](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#glmmod_toc.htm) will create a design matrix for you, which essentially means creating the dummy variables.

Answer (score 3):

No need to do this manually. There are a few SAS macros which can do this for you.  Here is one:

http://www.datavis.ca/sasmac/dummy.html